# How can I explain away job-hopping 3 jobs in a year?

Tags: human-resources

I was working in an IT company as a developer, then I got chance to work in an MNC company as a DBA, so I joined the new company.

After a week, they said DBA means "data analyser". I felt that I was cheated by them, thinking it meant "database administrator", so I quit that job in a week, and I joined a new company.

Now, my salary is low and there are no new opportunities. Also, my sir is going *abroad*, so my job is insecure. So I want to quit this job, but when I went for an interview, they were concerned that I had changed 3 jobs in a year, which created a bad impression.

What reason should I tell them?

Comment: than they ask y u want to leave this and sir i am feeling insecure

Comment: i am searching for an good opportunity ...if my sir will go abroad i will be *******....

Comment: You don't have to list all three jobs on your resume, or mention a short-term job at all for that matter. If you left a job in a week, there's really nothing to be gained by referencing it when job hunting.

Comment: In the job where you were told DBA meant "data analyzer", I really think quitting at that point was premature.  If you had felt unqualified for the "data analyzer" role, you could have mentioned this to your manager along with the usual explanation of DBA.  Otherwise, you could have buckled down and gone to work as a data analyzer.  If you really wanted to be a database administrator, you could have looked for such a position within the company.  If I were an employer, I would respect someone who stuck it out under those circumstances and at least tried to find their niche.

Comment: Related: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/3272/job-hopping-is-it-a-problem

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/21081/several-short-term-jobs-in-the-resume

Comment: You left the first job within a week.  That is within the trial period which makes it non-job-hopping.  Especially if you went and found something else quickly.  Question is if you need to mention it in your resume?

Comment: Also IF you get a new job, be sure that this is what you want, because you need to stay there for quite a while to avoid labeling yourself jobhopper for certain.

Answer (score 23):

Why do you feel compelled to list a job that only lasted two weeks?

A resume is not a legal document. It is an advertisement. When you list your qualifications, typically listing job experience is a part of that.  You are under no compulsion to list all of them.  If you need to explain a large gap, that's a thing, but assuming the gap is short, you are probably best off never mentioning it all.

Now, you are down to two jobs in a year and a small gap- may not be great, but it is fewer questions to answer.

---

*Clarification, based on a good comment.  If, after you have gotten through the interview, and been given a job, you may be asked to complete an application that says "Please list *all* jobs."  If you are feeling particularly supercilious, you should probably list it at that time - on the off chance somebody decides to do a full life audit. At worst, the hiring manager may ask, "What's this?" You say: "It's a job I held for two weeks.  It really wasn't worth mentioning, because ..." and you then explain.  The resume is about the first impression here - the application comes when it is pretty much a done deal.

Comment: The only way I'd mention a job that I held for a week is if I somehow saved the world from a major meteor collision that week. Otherwise, it's complete nonsense to mention job #2 especially since the OP moved on to his current job after that week. I don't know what possessed the OP to list a job that the OP held for only a week and that most likely, two of the five days in that week were spent locating co-workers and management, the restroom, the cafeteria, the alternative places to eat, filling out forms, etc.

Comment: I agree with this answer, but I could also clarify the other side that if you fill out an _application paper_ where it says to list all jobs, you have to do that. Even some more high-level jobs require such a paper, in my experience, and it is especially for this purpose.  When you sign that "this is complete and true" on that application paper, that is where they can hold it against you if you lie.

Comment: @MikeM, If an employer found out somehow and then made a big deal out of the omission of a 2 week stint (without accepting any explanation), it would probably be a bad idea to work for that employer!

Comment: @VietnhiPhuvan I would just list that under hobbies.

Answer (score 10):

**"I was looking for something that really fit me".**

I'd do my best to be honest, without blaming each of the companies. Portray it as a string of bad luck - first of all, you misunderstood the job description and thought you were making an exciting career move. When you realised you hadn't, you moved on. Unfortunately, the current job doesn't have a lot of room for growth.

"If I can find a company that focuses on professional development and fit (criterion x that is important to me)", I'm certain I'll be happy to stay put."

And before you accept any job offer... *make sure* you understand the role and the things they're asking you to do. Maybe even ask to have a chat with your co-workers or be shown around the building. If you're pickier about what you choose, you'll not need to jump ship so often :)

Comment: *make sure you understand the role and the things they're asking you to do* <== this is huge! I can't tell you how many times I've sat down for a job with one title that had responsibilities that don't fit at all. (Honestly more often than not this is an honest mistake. It's not hard to imagine a manager with no technical background not having a clue between Data Analyst, DBA, Data Migration Specialist, etc. To the non techie they see "Database" and go "yeah I need someone to database!"

Comment: Same kind of thing happened to my girlfriend, she was interviewing for a marketing/design position that turned out to have all the responsibilities of an administrative assistant along with it, which was not communicated to her in the interview. That lasted a day. The company was confused about what they were really interviewing for.