# How to reason two company changes within few months to a recruiter from dream company?

Tags: interviewing, software-industry, new-job, recruitment, tech-industry

I joined a company which was a very good tech company A, 9 months back and after a month got another opportunity B, overseas giving me double after tax and expenses savings. I wanted to have international exposure and the money was also good. So, I joined this company after 4 months working in A as VISA and other processes took some time.

Company B turned out to be a very slow-paced, old tech with people who don't want to change anything, slowing down my pace of learning a lot. It has a very good work-life balance though. Before this, I have always worked with very well known product companies with very low work-life balance but high learning. I am enjoying the new country and my savings.

Company A turned out to be a very good tech company within a few months. Google started approaching all the employees of this company. I haven't updated my Linkedin profile, so got a message from Google recruiter for an interview. I want to work for Google and it is like my dream company. I will have to take a salary cut though, but I am ok with it.

How should I justify my reason to the recruiter for leaving A in 4 months and then again being ready to start an interview with them after 5 months working in B? Should I ask him to reschedule it 6 months after, I am afraid they might not have a job opening at that time?

Comment: No will tell him, if I say yes for further discussion. Thats why also, need to prepare a reply for this situation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I explain away job-hopping 3 jobs in a year?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/30444/how-can-i-explain-away-job-hopping-3-jobs-in-a-year)

Comment: From the grapevine, it seems working at amazon and Google is not all roses. I would investigate a little. If the difference is substantial, I would not take a big pay cut.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just be honest about it.

You can say your current job at company B was an excellent opportunity, as it offered you the opportunity to live abroad.

You can also say that you're considering Google (despite the great parts of the job at B, including the international exposure), because it's your dream company (or a company you really admire) and you wouldn't pass the chance to join them given the opportunity.

There's nothing wrong with taking what seem to be once-in-a-lifetime opportunities and having had two of these in a row doesn't necessarily make you look like a job hopper, especially if the opportunities you're taking involve fast-tracking your career, which seems to be the case here.

Comment: I would prepare a good answer for the inevitable question: "How can we be sure you wont leave again in 6 months time?"

Answer (score 2):

Just tell the recruiter what you just described to us here. The reasons you stated for moving from A to B and the reasons for being interesting leaving company B sound perfectly reasonable. People move around in the tech industry. Don't make something up that's sure to confuse matters for you further down the interviewing process with Google.