# can i add my current one month job experience in resume?

Tags: software-industry, resume, job-change, software

I have been joined in a company as a software engineer fresher and worked for a month. I want to apply to other companies which are doing more exciting work and paying better. Can i add my current job as a experience in resume? How will it effect my resume? One point to mention is,  i **have not** worked in a project yet, just have completed few assignments.

**N.B**: i know there are few questions like this and i have gone through them.but none of them answered exactly for my case.

Comment: when invited to the interview, how will you answer the question "why did you leave your previous job?"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Several short-term jobs in the resume](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/21081/several-short-term-jobs-in-the-resume)

Comment: I would say, I deserve better opportunity.will it work?

Comment: Beware the word *deserve.* It subtly connotes arrogance. But do ask a friend to conduct a mock interview with you, so you can practice your response to the "why did you leave?" question.

Comment: I'd say the lack of a sustained job before this one makes it very different from the several short-term jobs in the resume question. I will note that at every employer where I've worked, if one waits for a project to fall out of a tree, it takes longer, sometimes as long as a year. But at all of these employers, there were projects that could be found and picked up by motivated employees. Grabbing one of these projects can be politically tricky, but if you feel out the options first, it can be a very good start to a career.

Answer (score 6):

Your questions were,

> Can i add my current job as a experience in resume?

Certainly you can - your resume is yours to write, you can put anything there that's truthful and helps represent your experience.

> How will it effect my resume?

If you're really trying to ask, "how will it affect my chance of getting hired?" then there's some unfortunate news - employers who see that you have little history and are trying to jump after only one month will consider you a flight risk - what's stopping you from immediately leaving them after they've hired you? In many cases, someone with a very short history, and who's looking for a new job after only one month will just get discarded from the search, unless there's some obvious or special circumstance.

If you do manage to land an interview, you need to be ready to answer questions about your short tenure, while inspiring confidence - you need to help employers understand that you're interested in a relationship that will be beneficial for them, and that you're not a poor planner.

It's also important to consider this a learning opportunity. What about this employer do you not like? What can you do during your job search to ensure that you're not going to make the same mistake again? If you feel so strongly about your current job that you're willing to leave so quickly, make sure you're taking the opportunity to focus on employers who won't leave you feeling the same way again and again in the future.

Answer (score 4):

> Can i add my current job as a experience in resume?

Certainly. You can add any experience that you think will help you.

> How will it effect my resume?

It will add very, very little to the strength of your resume. And it would likely raise some red flags regarding leaving so soon.

And of course it will raise the obvious question of "why do you want to leave this job when you have only been there for a month?"

Hopefully, you have much better reasons than just "doing more exciting work and paying better." Since you obviously knew how much you would be getting paid a month ago, the followup would be "then why did you take this job in the first place?"

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can put it on your resume- I mean you did work there for a month after all so its not like you're lying.

Some employers might find it alarming that you're applying to jobs just one month after joining a new company and it will almost be guaranteed to be brought up in an interview- if you get one. It can be a potential red flag to some employers.